# Code completion stopping work out of blue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, code-completion

I have an .pas file and in middle of programming - Code Completion stopped working. I removed IDEFixPack, which is suspect but nothing changed. What can be?

(I'll answer myself, just left this findind to community).

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

EDIT: I suspect that can be caused by strange line-endings (mixed CR, LR and CRLF throught the file):

```
unit Unit2;[CR]
[LF]
interface[CR][LF]
[LF]
uses[LF]
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,[CR]
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;[LF]
```

And so on...

Comment: There are tons of issues with code completion in the Delphi IDE. I find a new issue at least once or twice a month. Every occasion still seems random, and a different reason each time (for the few times I've managed to find reasons)

Comment: @JerryDodge: This is not. It's specific to an single .pas file. The question in link show an problem that happens even on an brand new project. And I solved the problem using Notepad++, just converting the problematic line ending to Window format. It's on answer.

Comment: If you are sure what it is specific to the particular file - let us look at it.

Comment: Nothing special about it, it was just the line endings.

Comment: voted to close. this is a duplicate and why should be a wiki?

Comment: That edit is good or needs more?

Comment: @RBA Just to get your attention back to this question, after a bit of back and forth OP has edited the question and it's really not a duplicate - I've retracted my close vote and down-vote. Just letting you know in case you wanted to change something too.

Comment: The Delphi IDE is such a mixed bag.  Some things it does exceptionally well, other things it just utterly fails at.  Code completion and Error Insight immediately come to mind.  Even the forms designer is riddled with bugs and oddities.  It almost seems like a paradox because the language itself, the compiler, and the RTL/VCL are comparatively so solid and great to work with.  I've all but given up on code completion in Delphi.  If I happen to be so lucky as to have it work, I take it, but otherwise you just sort of get used to betting on the fact that it's not going to be there.

Comment: Just as sidenote, the question is discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195169/201151)

Comment: It's kinda like owning a car that you have to start using a screwdriver, a paperclip, and a pair of tweezers at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One cause of this is: line-ending chars are mixed inside an source-file. Use Dos2Unix (in a batch) or Notepad++(if is just an single or few files) to correct this to Windows line-ending (CRLF) and the Code Completion will come back.
Happened to me right now and made me lose more than an hour trying to find what was happening. Of course, CC on delphi is bugged and this is just one cause. But is a devious one.

Comment: Because is quite an FAQ question and I don't want the rep.